# Complex Type definition violates unique particle attribution

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, complextype

The given definition of the type `MyType` should allow the element sequences (`A`), (`B`), (`C`), (`A`, `B`) and (`A`, `C`). On validation I get an "unique particle attribution violation" error. How can I fix this issue?

```
<xs:complexType name="MyType">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="A" type="AType"/>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="A" type="AType" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="B" type="BType"/>
        <xs:element name="C" type="CType"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some refactoring fixes the unique particle attribution error:

```
<xs:complexType name="MyType">
  <xs:choice>
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="A" type="AType"/>
       <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
         <xs:element name="B" type="BType"/>
         <xs:element name="C" type="CType"/>
       </xs:choice>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="B" type="BType"/>
     <xs:element name="C" type="CType"/>
   </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```